# Правильный синтаксис возврата таблицы, у которой одно поле - массив, из функции

Tags: postgresql

Помогите пожалуйста, не пойму как оформить синтаксис. У меня есть функция, которая должна вернуть таблицу, одно из полей которых - массив. Пользуюсь Navicat. Навикат ругается на синтаксис "other" text[], когда я в листинге функции пишу следующее

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."data_get"("id" int)
RETURNS TABLE("name" varchar, "age" int2, "other" text[]) AS $BODY$
```

говорит "Invalid stored procedure syntax", не нравится видимо ему text[]. Как мне синтаксически правильно написать возврат поля с типом массив?

Comment: это проблема Navicat, а не postgres'а... синаксис правильный...

Comment: Спасибо, понял.